# Group vector of structs by field

Tags: rust

I want to create a vector with all of the matching field `id` from the struct, process that new vector and then repeat the process. Basically grouping together the structs with matching field `id`.

Is there a way to do this by not using the unstable feature `drain_filter`?

```
#![feature(drain_filter)]

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Person {
    id: u32,
}

fn main() {

    let mut people = vec![];

    for p in 0..10 {
        people.push(Person { id: p });
    }

    while !people.is_empty() {
        let first_person_id = people.first().unwrap().id;

        let drained: Vec<Person> = people.drain_filter(|p| p.id == first_person_id).collect();

        println!("{:#?}", drained);
    }

}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=9b5ff220a22e60d55594db2a58fe315c)

Comment: `people.into_iter().partition(|p| p.id == first_person_id).collect()`?

Comment: That creates a tuple with the two vectors and doesn't drain the people vec, so the next loop will still have the original data

Comment: What is the actual use case of this? Your code doesn't really show what you're trying to do nor why it matters.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are looking to group your vector by the person id, it's likely to be more efficient using a HashMap from `id` to `Vec<Person>`, where each `id` hold a vector of persons. And then you can loop through the HashMap and process each vector / group. This is potentially more efficient than draining `people` in each iteration, which in worst case has O(N^2) time complexity while with a HashMap the time complexity is O(N).

```
#![feature(drain_filter)]
use std::collections::HashMap;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Person {
    id: u32,
}

fn main() {

    let mut people = vec![];
    let mut groups: HashMap<u32, Vec<Person>> = HashMap::new();

    for p in 0..10 {
        people.push(Person { id: p });
    }

    people.into_iter().for_each(|person| {
        let group = groups.entry(person.id).or_insert(vec![]);
        group.push(person);
    });

    for (_id, group) in groups {
        println!("{:#?}", group);
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=6b38342b36db776571543c714d87a07c)

Answer (score 1):

Remove unnecessary lines:

```
let group = groups.entry(person.id).or_insert(vec![]);
group.push(person);
```

by

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Person {
    id: u32,
}

fn main() {
    let mut people = vec![];
    let mut groups: HashMap<u32, Vec<Person>> = HashMap::new();

    for p in 0..10 {
        people.push(Person { id: p });
    }

    people.into_iter().for_each(|person| {
        groups
            .entry(person.id)
            // If there's no entry for the key, create a new Vec and return a mutable ref to it
            .or_default()
            // and insert the item onto the Vec
            .push(person);
    });

    for (_id, group) in groups {
        println!("{:#?}", group);
    }
}
```